# how does it improve EFT immunity

Tags: protection, emc

how does this design really improve EFT immunity.

[image]

where does EFT come from i guess (VDD) as spike ?
in my estimation i would say (10k+100nF) is more robust from changes on VDD?

in fact the 100pF is low impedance at high frequencies so its shorting reset pin to VDD ?

im really confused ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I need to say this first: -

An external reset button (as stated in the picture in the question) means a button that is connected to the equipment through a port on the box of the equipment that is being tested. An internal button on the PCB of the equipment is **not** subject to EFT testing.

In other words this only applies to an external button as per this: -

> *The repetitive EFT test consists of a number of fast transients
> coupled into power supply, control, and signal ports of electrical and
> electronic equipment.*

Above quote taken from [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/917933). You don't need to access the whole document; just the quote above. In effect an external reset port is regarded as a control port and may be subject to testing.

So, a reset button wired to a piece of equipment may be subject to EFT and, the capacitor soaks up the energy of the EFT and largely prevents a reset. In other words, the capacitor acts like a low pass filter and significantly attenuates high frequency (EFT) noise. This prevents false external resets.

> *in fact the 100pF is low impedance at high frequencies so its shorting
> reset pin to VDD ?*

That's one way of putting it - it acts like a short to the EFT and, keeps the reset pin close to the same voltage as \$V_{DD}\$.

Answer (score 2):

An example --- 1pf at 1Ghz has impedance of -j_159 ohms.

And 100 pf has impedance of 1.59 ohms.

Thus, given ONE ohm needs ONE amp thru it, to develope just ONE volt, this 100pf capacitor requires the external EFT to provide lots of current if logic_threshold (or damage_level) voltages are to be reached.

Answer (score 1):

For the capacitor connecting RESET to Vdd:

A capacitor appears as a short-circuit for high frequencies. That means if there is an EFT event trying to pull the line LO, it is shorted to Vdd and can't produce a voltage drop across the 10K resistor to pull the line LO to cause a reset.

Imagine what would happen if you removed the 10K and the capacitor and just connected RESET to Vdd. It's going to be really difficult for anything to pull the RESET line LO.

The EFT would probably not be coming from Vdd. It would be some noise induced or injected onto the RESET pin itself.

---

For the capacitor connecting RESET to GND:

It still works the same way as above except the high frequency EFT is shorted to GND instead of Vdd so doesn't appear on the RESET pin. But in this case, the cap is charged up to Vdd (it has Vdd across the cap) so any EFT induced onto the RESET pin must also be enough to drain the cap charge enough so that the pin voltage goes to GND before anything will happen. This protect against helps low frequency glitches.